# MacMini Dual Screen dragging window to secondary screen failed to land desired location

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, osx-yosemite

When I drag a window to the top area of the secondary screen, it won't follow the cursor to the desired location, but jumps to the middle of the screen. It worked fine before the Yosemite upgrade.

Is this a setting problem? My two screens are set up with primary horizontal and secondary vertical on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Check System Prefs > Displays > Arrangement
that the arrangement resembles this…

[image]

rather than this...

[image]

If not you can simply drag either monitor to its new location.

<sup>(Quickly knocked up in photoshop, so not an exact representation)</sup>

Comment: Tetsujin, actually my setting is exactly the second one...is there any special reason that I can't use that setting? I need to level two mon that way to have a smooth dragging(no visually interrupt).

Comment: then it should drag naturally from the top of screen 1 to the centre[ish] of screen 2, then need dragging higher to reach the top of screen 2. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: I can drag to S[creen]2 to the centre with no problem. the problem took place when I drag to the top of S2 in one drag, the window just jumped back to the middle.

Comment: hmm… not sure then - does it do it with all apps, every time?

Comment: ya, pretty much everything every time.

Comment: then I've really no clue, sorry - I've never run that type of setup before, with one landscape, one portrait